# Magento 2.0.7 - catalogsearch_fulltext index

Tags: magento2

1. Reindexing `catalogsearch_fulltext` index (via CLI) gets terminated. I tried hundreds times now and still receive this error. Why is it getting terminated?
2. If `catalogsearch_fulltext` index is not fully rebuilt, won't products visible in frontend in category pages, or simply they won't be available to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In `pub/.htaccess` there were too little memory set for PHP. It was 256MB. Increased to 1024MB and it's working now as a charm.
2. Yes, if `catalogsearch_fulltext` is not fully rebuilt, you won't get all your products in frontend.